# Запись и чтение из канала golang

Tags: golang, concurrency

Всем привет.
Ниже пример кода, просьба подсказать почему вторая горутина быстрее пишет в канал:
https://play.golang.org/p/olYKJ08L5C

```
    c := make(chan string)
    go func(s string){
        c <- s
    }("first")
    go func(s string){
        c <- s
    }("second")
    fmt.Println(<-c, <-c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок следования горутин не определён. Когда вы делаете `go f(a)`, нет никакой гарантии, когда `f(a)` начнёт выполняться. См. например документ [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem), где описано, что после чего происходит.

Если вам нужен ясный порядок, то во-первых, непонятно, зачем вам горутины, а во-вторых, вам надо самому прописать механизм синхронизации.

Comment: Пример кода взят с https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/concurrency/2
Хочется понять почему горутина, которая объявлена второй, пишет в канал быстрее и также если их поменять местами, первая будет быстрее писать в канал
Как я понимаю, первая горутина должна захватить канал и записать туда данные, вторая же не может туда ничего писать, пока с канала данные не были считаны

Comment: @Sandman Ещё раз, порядок запуска горутин не имеет никакого значения, потому что он не определён. В одной версии вторая запускается перед первой, в другой -  наоборот, в третьей - рандомно. Ваша задача - создавать программы, которые не завязываются на порядок.

Comment: Большое спасибо)